# Prepared SQL statement in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl, I'm trying to overcome the initial learning curve.

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    node_id 
FROM 
    pagenodes
INNER JOIN 
    pageproducts 
ON 
    pagenodes.node_id = pageproducts.nodeid
INNER JOIN 
    products 
ON 
    pageproducts.prodid = products.prodid 
WHERE 
    products.prodid  = ?
LIMIT 1
```

As you can see this has LIMIT 1 set in the query, I'm trying to perform this query from a Perl script, and set the result to a variable.

So far I have the following:

```
my $sql =
    'SELECT 
        node_id 
    FROM 
        pagenodes
    INNER JOIN 
        pageproducts 
    ON 
        pagenodes.node_id = pageproducts.nodeid
    INNER JOIN 
        products 
    ON 
        pageproducts.prodid = products.prodid 
    WHERE 
        products.prodid  = ?
    LIMIT 1';
    
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    my $sth->execute();
```

My question is, how can I pass in `$prod_id` as the WHERE paramater, and how can I set the result to a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're pretty far already. It's great that you already have [the placeholders (`?`)](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values). All you need to do is pass the parameter [as an argument to `execute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute). It will fill them into the placeholders automatically, in the order they appear in your query.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dsn goes here', 'user', 'password') or die $DBI::errstr;

# stuff happens ...

my $prod_id = 1337; # or whatever

my $sql =
    'SELECT 
        node_id 
    FROM 
        pagenodes
    INNER JOIN 
        pageproducts 
    ON 
        pagenodes.node_id = pageproducts.nodeid
    INNER JOIN 
        products 
    ON 
        pageproducts.prodid = products.prodid 
    WHERE 
        products.prodid  = ?
    LIMIT 1';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($prod_id);     # no `my` here!
```

The `LIMIT` in this case doesn't matter. It will also work in a loop.

Note that you had a `my` in front of the `execute` line. That is wrong syntax. `my` is used to *declare* variables, but in that line you only call a method on the already existing statement handle object. There is a return value for the `execute` method, but it is usually not assigned to a variable. If the return value is true, the `execute` was successful. If it's false, something went wrong. You can also use `or` to [check for errors](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#errstr).

```
$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Now to get your single value from the database, you can [use `fetchrow_array` in list context](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array).

```
( my $node_id ) = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

This will give you the single `node_id`, once.

---

If you intend to only get one value and only call this once, you can also save some lines of code and [use `selectrow_array` instead](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectrow_array).

```
( my $node_id ) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT node_id FROM foo WHERE prodid=? LIMIT 1', undef, $prod_id);
```

Again, the list context is important, because `fetchrow_array` and `selectrow_array` return lists, not array references. Without the `()` around the left hand side, it would assign the number of results (because of scalar context).

If, however, you want to do all this in a loop for a bunch of values, it looks a bit different. In that case, do your prepare outside of the loop and just `execute` and `fetchrow_array` (or any of the other `fetchrow_*` methods) inside of the loop. That will make it considerably faster.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
foreach my $prod_id ( @prod_ids ) {
  $sth->execute($prod_id);
  ( my $node_id ) = $sth->fetchrow_array;
  print "$node_id\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe also check out [the excellent slides of Tim Bunce's presentation on advanced DBI at OSCON](http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/dbi-advanced-tutorial-2007).

Comment: That's a fantastic answer thanks for that. I seem to be pulling an error: "Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name" I'm just looking in to that.

Comment: @Liam did you load DBI and connect to the database at all?

Comment: I've just changed the config of the connection and have this working! Thank you

Comment: `$prod_id` needs to be declared and definec

Comment: @Borodin true, I implied that's the stuff that happens. But I'll add it explicitly.

Comment: @simbabque: I realise that. But it didn't sit right that you had `use strict` in there without the necessary declaration. I think you should either write a code fragment or a working program, and it should be clear somehow which of those it is. Not that I always succeed myself :-/

Comment: @Liam: I think it would help you a lot if you submitted your working code to [*Code Review*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You will be treated very gently there unless you post crap like code that won't even compile, and it may well help you to learn some of the subtleties of the language

Comment: @borodin I agree, it's more consistent. And I agree with the code review as well. Maybe I should head over to CR a bit more often, but the Perl tag seems very slow and then people jump on new questions even more than here.